# Moodle XMLDB how to apply the scema into my database

Tags: php, xml, database, moodle

Using the XMLDB editor that is provided in moodle I created the following schema for a custom block:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<XMLDB PATH="blocks/userlist/db" VERSION="20190504" COMMENT="XMLDB file for Moodle blocks/userlist"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../lib/xmldb/xmldb.xsd"
>
  <TABLES>
    <TABLE NAME="block_userlist" COMMENT="Statistics on user Activity.">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD NAME="id" TYPE="int" LENGTH="10" NOTNULL="true" SEQUENCE="true"/>
        <FIELD NAME="logout_time" TYPE="int" LENGTH="10" NOTNULL="false" SEQUENCE="false" COMMENT="Time that a user logs out."/>
        <FIELD NAME="login_time" TYPE="int" LENGTH="10" NOTNULL="true" SEQUENCE="false" COMMENT="Time that a user has logged in"/>
        <FIELD NAME="session_duration" TYPE="int" LENGTH="10" NOTNULL="false" SEQUENCE="false" COMMENT="How long that a user has logged in"/>
      </FIELDS>
      <KEYS>
        <KEY NAME="primary" TYPE="foreign" FIELDS="id" REFTABLE="user" REFFIELDS="id"/>
      </KEYS>
    </TABLE>
  </TABLES>
</XMLDB>
```

And I want to load it into my database of my current moodle installation in order to perform operations in it. Thus I want to ask on how to do that?

I had a look over the https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Using_XMLDB#Create_new_table but I see no way to apply the schema changes. Furthermore I had a look over my database's tables in order to find out if the table has been created but is seems has not:

```
| m_analytics_indicator_calc     |
| m_analytics_models             |
| m_analytics_models_log         |
| m_analytics_predict_samples    |
| m_analytics_prediction_actions |
| m_analytics_predictions        |
| m_analytics_train_samples      |
| m_analytics_used_analysables   |
| m_analytics_used_files         |
| m_assign                       |
| m_assign_grades                |
| m_assign_overrides             |
| m_assign_plugin_config         |
| m_assign_submission            |
| m_assign_user_flags            |
| m_assign_user_mapping          |
| m_assignfeedback_comments      |
| m_assignfeedback_editpdf_annot |
| m_assignfeedback_editpdf_cmnt  |
| m_assignfeedback_editpdf_queue |
| m_assignfeedback_editpdf_quick |
| m_assignfeedback_file          |
| m_assignment                   |
| m_assignment_submissions       |
| m_assignment_upgrade           |
| m_assignsubmission_file        |
| m_assignsubmission_onlinetext  |
| m_auth_oauth2_linked_login     |
| m_backup_controllers           |
| m_backup_courses               |
| m_backup_logs                  |
| m_badge                        |
| m_badge_backpack               |
| m_badge_competencies           |
| m_badge_criteria               |
| m_badge_criteria_met           |
| m_badge_criteria_param         |
| m_badge_endorsement            |
| m_badge_external               |
| m_badge_issued                 |
| m_badge_manual_award           |
| m_badge_related                |
| m_block                        |
| m_block_community              |
| m_block_instances              |
| m_block_positions              |
| m_block_recent_activity        |
| m_block_recentlyaccesseditems  |
| m_block_rss_client             |
| m_blog_association             |
| m_blog_external                |
| m_book                         |
| m_book_chapters                |
| m_cache_filters                |
| m_cache_flags                  |
| m_capabilities                 |
| m_chat                         |
| m_chat_messages                |
| m_chat_messages_current        |
| m_chat_users                   |
| m_choice                       |
| m_choice_answers               |
| m_choice_options               |
| m_cohort                       |
| m_cohort_members               |
| m_comments                     |
| m_competency                   |
| m_competency_coursecomp        |
| m_competency_coursecompsetting |
| m_competency_evidence          |
| m_competency_framework         |
| m_competency_modulecomp        |
| m_competency_plan              |
| m_competency_plancomp          |
| m_competency_relatedcomp       |
| m_competency_template          |
| m_competency_templatecohort    |
| m_competency_templatecomp      |
| m_competency_usercomp          |
| m_competency_usercompcourse    |
| m_competency_usercompplan      |
| m_competency_userevidence      |
| m_competency_userevidencecomp  |
| m_config                       |
| m_config_log                   |
| m_config_plugins               |
| m_context                      |
| m_context_temp                 |
| m_course                       |
| m_course_categories            |
| m_course_completion_aggr_methd |
| m_course_completion_crit_compl |
| m_course_completion_criteria   |
| m_course_completion_defaults   |
| m_course_completions           |
| m_course_format_options        |
| m_course_modules               |
| m_course_modules_completion    |
| m_course_published             |
| m_course_request               |
| m_course_sections              |
| m_data                         |
| m_data_content                 |
| m_data_fields                  |
| m_data_records                 |
| m_editor_atto_autosave         |
| m_enrol                        |
| m_enrol_flatfile               |
| m_enrol_lti_lti2_consumer      |
| m_enrol_lti_lti2_context       |
| m_enrol_lti_lti2_nonce         |
| m_enrol_lti_lti2_resource_link |
| m_enrol_lti_lti2_share_key     |
| m_enrol_lti_lti2_tool_proxy    |
| m_enrol_lti_lti2_user_result   |
| m_enrol_lti_tool_consumer_map  |
| m_enrol_lti_tools              |
| m_enrol_lti_users              |
| m_enrol_paypal                 |
| m_event                        |
| m_event_subscriptions          |
| m_events_handlers              |
| m_events_queue                 |
| m_events_queue_handlers        |
| m_external_functions           |
| m_external_services            |
| m_external_services_functions  |
| m_external_services_users      |
| m_external_tokens              |
| m_favourite                    |
| m_feedback                     |
| m_feedback_completed           |
| m_feedback_completedtmp        |
| m_feedback_item                |
| m_feedback_sitecourse_map      |
| m_feedback_template            |
| m_feedback_value               |
| m_feedback_valuetmp            |
| m_file_conversion              |
| m_files                        |
| m_files_reference              |
| m_filter_active                |
| m_filter_config                |
| m_folder                       |
| m_forum                        |
| m_forum_digests                |
| m_forum_discussion_subs        |
| m_forum_discussions            |
| m_forum_posts                  |
| m_forum_queue                  |
| m_forum_read                   |
| m_forum_subscriptions          |
| m_forum_track_prefs            |
| m_glossary                     |
| m_glossary_alias               |
| m_glossary_categories          |
| m_glossary_entries             |
| m_glossary_entries_categories  |
| m_glossary_formats             |
| m_grade_categories             |
| m_grade_categories_history     |
| m_grade_grades                 |
| m_grade_grades_history         |
| m_grade_import_newitem         |
| m_grade_import_values          |
| m_grade_items                  |
| m_grade_items_history          |
| m_grade_letters                |
| m_grade_outcomes               |
| m_grade_outcomes_courses       |
| m_grade_outcomes_history       |
| m_grade_settings               |
| m_grading_areas                |
| m_grading_definitions          |
| m_grading_instances            |
| m_gradingform_guide_comments   |
| m_gradingform_guide_criteria   |
| m_gradingform_guide_fillings   |
| m_gradingform_rubric_criteria  |
| m_gradingform_rubric_fillings  |
| m_gradingform_rubric_levels    |
| m_groupings                    |
| m_groupings_groups             |
| m_groups                       |
| m_groups_members               |
| m_imscp                        |
| m_label                        |
| m_lesson                       |
| m_lesson_answers               |
| m_lesson_attempts              |
| m_lesson_branch                |
| m_lesson_grades                |
| m_lesson_overrides             |
| m_lesson_pages                 |
| m_lesson_timer                 |
| m_license                      |
| m_lock_db                      |
| m_log                          |
| m_log_display                  |
| m_log_queries                  |
| m_logstore_standard_log        |
| m_lti                          |
| m_lti_submission               |
| m_lti_tool_proxies             |
| m_lti_tool_settings            |
| m_lti_types                    |
| m_lti_types_config             |
| m_ltiservice_gradebookservices |
| m_message                      |
| m_message_airnotifier_devices  |
| m_message_contact_requests     |
| m_message_contacts             |
| m_message_conversation_members |
| m_message_conversations        |
| m_message_popup                |
| m_message_popup_notifications  |
| m_message_processors           |
| m_message_providers            |
| m_message_read                 |
| m_message_user_actions         |
| m_message_users_blocked        |
| m_messageinbound_datakeys      |
| m_messageinbound_handlers      |
| m_messageinbound_messagelist   |
| m_messages                     |
| m_mnet_application             |
| m_mnet_host                    |
| m_mnet_host2service            |
| m_mnet_log                     |
| m_mnet_remote_rpc              |
| m_mnet_remote_service2rpc      |
| m_mnet_rpc                     |
| m_mnet_service                 |
| m_mnet_service2rpc             |
| m_mnet_session                 |
| m_mnet_sso_access_control      |
| m_mnetservice_enrol_courses    |
| m_mnetservice_enrol_enrolments |
| m_modules                      |
| m_my_pages                     |
| m_notifications                |
| m_oauth2_access_token          |
| m_oauth2_endpoint              |
| m_oauth2_issuer                |
| m_oauth2_system_account        |
| m_oauth2_user_field_mapping    |
| m_page                         |
| m_portfolio_instance           |
| m_portfolio_instance_config    |
| m_portfolio_instance_user      |
| m_portfolio_log                |
| m_portfolio_mahara_queue       |
| m_portfolio_tempdata           |
| m_post                         |
| m_profiling                    |
| m_qtype_ddimageortext          |
| m_qtype_ddimageortext_drags    |
| m_qtype_ddimageortext_drops    |
| m_qtype_ddmarker               |
| m_qtype_ddmarker_drags         |
| m_qtype_ddmarker_drops         |
| m_qtype_essay_options          |
| m_qtype_match_options          |
| m_qtype_match_subquestions     |
| m_qtype_multichoice_options    |
| m_qtype_randomsamatch_options  |
| m_qtype_shortanswer_options    |
| m_question                     |
| m_question_answers             |
| m_question_attempt_step_data   |
| m_question_attempt_steps       |
| m_question_attempts            |
| m_question_calculated          |
| m_question_calculated_options  |
| m_question_categories          |
| m_question_dataset_definitions |
| m_question_dataset_items       |
| m_question_datasets            |
| m_question_ddwtos              |
| m_question_gapselect           |
| m_question_hints               |
| m_question_multianswer         |
| m_question_numerical           |
| m_question_numerical_options   |
| m_question_numerical_units     |
| m_question_response_analysis   |
| m_question_response_count      |
| m_question_statistics          |
| m_question_truefalse           |
| m_question_usages              |
| m_quiz                         |
| m_quiz_attempts                |
| m_quiz_feedback                |
| m_quiz_grades                  |
| m_quiz_overrides               |
| m_quiz_overview_regrades       |
| m_quiz_reports                 |
| m_quiz_sections                |
| m_quiz_slot_tags               |
| m_quiz_slots                   |
| m_quiz_statistics              |
| m_rating                       |
| m_registration_hubs            |
| m_repository                   |
| m_repository_instance_config   |
| m_repository_instances         |
| m_repository_onedrive_access   |
| m_resource                     |
| m_resource_old                 |
| m_role                         |
| m_role_allow_assign            |
| m_role_allow_override          |
| m_role_allow_switch            |
| m_role_allow_view              |
| m_role_assignments             |
| m_role_capabilities            |
| m_role_context_levels          |
| m_role_names                   |
| m_role_sortorder               |
| m_scale                        |
| m_scale_history                |
| m_scorm                        |
| m_scorm_aicc_session           |
| m_scorm_scoes                  |
| m_scorm_scoes_data             |
| m_scorm_scoes_track            |
| m_scorm_seq_mapinfo            |
| m_scorm_seq_objective          |
| m_scorm_seq_rolluprule         |
| m_scorm_seq_rolluprulecond     |
| m_scorm_seq_rulecond           |
| m_scorm_seq_ruleconds          |
| m_search_index_requests        |
| m_search_simpledb_index        |
| m_sessions                     |
| m_stats_daily                  |
| m_stats_monthly                |
| m_stats_user_daily             |
| m_stats_user_monthly           |
| m_stats_user_weekly            |
| m_stats_weekly                 |
| m_survey                       |
| m_survey_analysis              |
| m_survey_answers               |
| m_survey_questions             |
| m_tag                          |
| m_tag_area                     |
| m_tag_coll                     |
| m_tag_correlation              |
| m_tag_instance                 |
| m_task_adhoc                   |
| m_task_scheduled               |
| m_tool_cohortroles             |
| m_tool_customlang              |
| m_tool_customlang_components   |
| m_tool_dataprivacy_category    |
| m_tool_dataprivacy_ctxexpired  |
| m_tool_dataprivacy_ctxinstance |
| m_tool_dataprivacy_ctxlevel    |
| m_tool_dataprivacy_purpose     |
| m_tool_dataprivacy_purposerole |
| m_tool_dataprivacy_request     |
| m_tool_monitor_events          |
| m_tool_monitor_history         |
| m_tool_monitor_rules           |
| m_tool_monitor_subscriptions   |
| m_tool_policy                  |
| m_tool_policy_acceptances      |
| m_tool_policy_versions         |
| m_tool_recyclebin_category     |
| m_tool_recyclebin_course       |
| m_tool_usertours_steps         |
| m_tool_usertours_tours         |
| m_upgrade_log                  |
| m_url                          |
| m_user                         |
| m_user_devices                 |
| m_user_enrolments              |
| m_user_info_category           |
| m_user_info_data               |
| m_user_info_field              |
| m_user_lastaccess              |
| m_user_password_history        |
| m_user_password_resets         |
| m_user_preferences             |
| m_user_private_key             |
| m_wiki                         |
| m_wiki_links                   |
| m_wiki_locks                   |
| m_wiki_pages                   |
| m_wiki_subwikis                |
| m_wiki_synonyms                |
| m_wiki_versions                |
| m_workshop                     |
| m_workshop_aggregations        |
| m_workshop_assessments         |
| m_workshop_grades              |
| m_workshop_submissions         |
| m_workshopallocation_scheduled |
| m_workshopeval_best_settings   |
| m_workshopform_accumulative    |
| m_workshopform_comments        |
| m_workshopform_numerrors       |
| m_workshopform_numerrors_map   |
| m_workshopform_rubric          |
| m_workshopform_rubric_config   |
| m_workshopform_rubric_levels   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in the db/ subfolder of your custom plugin, then visit the "notifications" page of your Moodle site to trigger the install of your plugin (it should already be in the right place if the XMLDB editor was used to create it).

If your plugin is already installed, then you can uninstall your plugin via Site admin > Plugins > Manage plugins (this won't remove the code, but will remove all data associated with the plugin). After the uninstall is complete, click on "Continue" and, assuming you haven't deleted the code for your plugin, Moodle will spot it as a new plugin and install it, with the database table.

The other alternative is to use the XMLDB editor to generate the upgrade steps needed to go in db/upgrade.php, bump the plugin version number and trigger the upgrade.

See https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Upgrade_API for more details.